# Do we know any examples of complex surfaces where we have explicit knowledge of the Chern–Weil functions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, characteristic-classes, chern-classes

Let $X$ be a compact complex surface (smooth). Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ denote the Chern–Weil functions. That is, if $\omega$ is a Kähler form on $X$ with volume form $\omega^2$, then $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are functions such that $$c_1(X) = \int_X \gamma_1 \omega^2, \quad c_2(X)=\int_X\gamma_2\omega^2.$$ In other words, the Chern–Weil functions are the functions for which the Chern classes are given by their $L^1$-norms. We have a good list of examples where we know constraints of the form $$a c_1^2(X) \leq b c_2(X) \leq k c_1^2(X)$$ for $a,b,k\in \mathbb{R}$. I'm asking for something stronger; namely:

> Do we know concrete examples of surfaces for which $\gamma_1^2$ and $\gamma_2$ are known?

If you give me, for instance, a Barlow surface, or Beauville surface of some type, or some other surface, can we get information on the relations between $\gamma_1^2$ and $\gamma_2$? I *do not mean* "well, you can't have this relation, because integrating it would violate the Chern class inequality" — I'm not asking for *non-relations*, I'm asking for relations on the Chern–Weil functions.

I'd be very surprised and pleased if such knowledge exists, but I'm doubtful.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this concept?

Comment: @WillSawin Dear Will, thank you for your comment. If, by concept, you mean that of Chern-Weil functions: I'm referring to Siu, YT., Yang, P. Compact Kähler-Einstein surfaces of nonpositive bisectional curvature. Invent Math 64, 471–487 (1981). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01389278

Comment: Complex tori with flat metrics.

Comment: @JasonStarr Dear Jason, thank you for your comment. I was expecting this comment eventually. Are there non-flat examples?

Comment: For. ball quotients I think $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ will be constant functions, as the metric is locally homogeneous, so we have $\gamma_1^2 =3 \gamma_2=$ a constant depending on the normalization of the metric.

Comment: Is the first integral supposed to be $c_1^2?

Answer (score 6):

If you know the volume form, then you are asking for explicit formulas for the Chern-Weil representatives of $c_1$ and $c_2$. These would come from explicit formulas for the curvature. The calculation of the curvature for a hypersurface of ${\mathbb C}P^3$, with respect to the (restriction of) the Fubini-Study metric was carried out by Al Vitter in [On the curvature of complex hypersurfaces](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/docs/23067/23067.asp), Indiana Univ. Math. J. 23 (1973/74), 813–826."

Comment: Dear Danny, thank you for this answer. I'll take a look at this paper, and add a further comment after.

Comment: Dear Danny, I'm confused by the Vitter's Proposition 5. In the notation of Proposition 5, let us set $R := | b_z(X,X) |^2/ \| \partial_z f \|^2$. Then the holomorphic sectional curvature is $1 - \frac{1}{2}R$, which is negative if $R > 2$. On the other hand, the bisectional curvature is $\frac{1}{2}(1-R)$, which is negative if $R>1$. It seems to imply that negative holomorphic sectional curvature implies negative bisectional curvature, which is obviously false. Have I missed something in Vitter's notation?

Comment: I suggest you drop the author a line and ask him. He is listed on the Tulane web page as an emeritus professor.